# Add components to a class form/panel from another class (Java)

Tags: java, class, user-interface, inheritance

I am relatively new to programming in Java and I wish to be able to add controls to a GUI I made in another class because I will be using it several times.  The only way I can do this is by making the form and panel from the super class global, so i can access it in the child Class.  However I am sure I have read I should only make things global or persistent when there is no other choice.

Is there another way or is this acceptable.  Many thanks.  I have added the classes below as an example.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class BasicForm {

    JFrame frmBasic;
    JPanel panContainer;

    public BasicForm() {

        frmBasic = new JFrame();
        frmBasic.setTitle("Created By Inspired IT");
        frmBasic.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frmBasic.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        

        panContainer = new JPanel();
        panContainer.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 3));
        frmBasic.getContentPane().add(panContainer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panContainer.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblLogo = new JLabel("");
        Image img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/logo.png")).getImage();
        lblLogo.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        lblLogo.setBounds(343, 11, 81, 102);        
        panContainer.add(lblLogo);

        frmBasic.setVisible(true);          
    }       
}


public class FormGUI extends BasicForm {

    public FormGUI() {

        JButton btnContinue = new JButton("Continue");
        btnContinue.setBounds(336, 228, 88, 23);
        this.panContainer.add(btnContinue);             
    }       
}
```

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Take the functionality you want to re-use and create a custom class of it, probably extending from something like `JPanel` (or other basic container class based on the functionality you are trying to re-use), this way, you can just create a new instance of the class and add it to what ever container you want

Comment: I appreciate the feed back, I am currently completing an HND and in my second year,  our tutor told us we should use the null layout however, I will look in to other methods.  Thank you.

Comment: Get yourself a new tutor, they are giving your bad advice